# How to explicitly sort by the default sort order in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table where there are two fields that make up the primary key, and a "sort" field. None of these are auto-incrementing.

When you do a query on the table without specifying an `ORDER BY` clause, it pulls the data out in the order that it was put in -- pretty standard. So whichever rows were inserted first, it pulls those out first.

The problem is that when I `ORDER BY sort ASC`, if `sort` is null, then it really doesn't sort at all and the results just become jumbled up. But I want to have the backup `ORDER BY` be that default order that it would otherwise pull out of. I can't have the backup be an auto-incrementing "ID" field, because there is no auto-incrementing ID field. The primary key is just a combination of two foreign keys.

**-----EDIT-----**

### Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_attribute_select_value` (
  `product_attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_select_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_attribute_id`,`attribute_select_value_id`),
  KEY `product_attribute_select_value_FI_2` (`attribute_select_value_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `product_attribute_select_value`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_attribute_select_value_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_attribute_id`) REFERENCES `product_attribute` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_attribute_select_value_FK_2` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_select_value_id`) REFERENCES `attribute_select_value` (`id`);
```

### Data:

The data is inserted, and when pulled out without an `ORDER BY` clause, it comes out in the order it was put in. When there is an `ORDER BY` clause and all of the `sort` values are `0`, it pulls it out in a seemingly random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you want but can't really come out with a perfect solution.

Here are my 2 alternatives:

- Sort in your app
- Add a timestamp column or
  autoincrement column for the sake of
  backup sort:   `.... ORDER BY sort,
  SORTCOLUMN ASC`

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I accepted your answer because of your first alternative... sorting in the app. I don't know why I didn't think of that before. I basically now just have it pull out of the DB with no `ORDER BY` clause, and I sort based on either the sort value, if present, or the order it came out. Thanks again.

Comment: One of the things that SQL does VERY efficiently is sorting.  Unless one only expects relatively small results sets (and even so), or maybe unless someone has a very complicated sort-order with odd business rules etc., I'm puzzled as to why someone would consider sorting (or filtering) at the level of the application.

Comment: @mjv, it's because I'm only going to be dealing with 10-20 rows and I can't create a new auto-incrementing field (there is already tons of data in the DB). So it just makes sense in this case to do it on the app level. But in most other cases, sorting in the DB would be the obvious first choice.

Comment: @James: I called it an alternative because as much as possible, I'll leave sorting or data crunching to the DB server (as suggested by mjv). I guess 20, 30 rows is fine for the app to handle without significant performance hit. :)

Comment: @James On which basis are you going to sort, app-side, that you couldn't do SQL-side? Maybe you can post more detail about the table schema, or many a example of a short result set with the "jumbled-up" ouput.  (not trying to pester you or hunt for reps etc., just trying to understand myself a situation where client-side sorting is preferable/necessary)

Comment: @mjv: I don't think it's a case of "necessary", more of "convenience" perhaps. I'm not trying to retain my rep points too, will gladly see a more suitable answer. :P

Comment: @mjv, I posted some more detail about the situation. If there is a way to do it via SQL, then I will gladly change by answer, but it just seems like the only reasonable way to do it without adding a new auto-incrementing field (as there is already data in there) would be to do it app-side. What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 5):

First off, it is important to know that, in the absence of an ORDER BY clause, **the SQL standard does not prescribe the SQL implementations to produce the rows in any particular order**, in fact there is not even an expectation that the order produced be consistent for similar queries !

It is therefore generally dangerous to rely on the idea of a "natural order" provided by the implementation, unless explicitly documented by the particular DBMS producer (and I don't believe this is the case with MySQL), this "natural order" could change at any time (any new release, any change of content within the database, even!)

There is a trick to deal with null values, however:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(sort, 'zzzzzzz')
```

where 'zzzzzz' is a value which is bigger or smaller than any expected value for the "sort" column, resuting in placing the null rows at the end or at the beginning.  We typically use this technique to override the default behavior of MySQL which is to consider NULL values as the smallest, and hence placing first in an "ASC" sort and last in a "DESC" sort.
This [**working with null values**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/working-with-null.html) in the MySQL documentation.

It is also possible to add an additional column for the sort, maybe something like

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(sort, 'zzzzzzz') , id
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the awesome explanation and a great way to deal with `null` values (will definitely keep it in mind).

Answer (score 2):

Without an order by clause there is no guarantee as to the order the rows will come back. They generally do come back in the order they were inserted, but again, that is not something you can really rely on. Your best bet is to add an auto incrementing id that you can sort on as a backup. That will allow you to sort based on insertion order if that's what you want your backup sort to be.

Comment: Thanks for the great response Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

to make sure index is used for sorting you may try also following idea:

```
select ... where sort is not null order by sort asc
union
select ... where sort is null
```

this should work in 99%, but you shouldn't rely too much that nulls will be at the end (because that is not officially guaranteed)